# Failed to Selenium scroll a sidebar/container

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm new to selenium and python.the website have a sidebar (container) and I want to copy it's content (scraping) multiple times while scrolling until the end of that container.

The problem is that when I try to scroll this sidebar to download, more data to my browser so I can copy paste it with selenium. It doesn't scroll.

I ensure that the sidebar is visible and tried with

```
 is_displayed() result = visible
```

and also tried:

```
1- driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 2000);")
2- ActionChains
```

The same code works with other pages / containers

**side note:** Not sure if this matters but the simple copy or select with mouse inside this (container) requires the use of a Chrome extension called "Absolute Enable Right Click & Copy" it's protected with some JS. I guess
that's part of the code I tried (I'm not getting any errors)

**python**

```
last_height = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight;", member_container)
scroll_by = 2000
# Loop until the scroll position no longer changes
while True:
    # Scroll the member list container by the specified amount
    driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].scrollBy(0, {scroll_by});", member_container)

    # Wait for the page to load
    time.sleep(5)

    # Get the new scroll position
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight;", member_container)

    # Check if the scroll position has changed
    if new_height == last_height:
        # Exit the loop if the scroll position no longer changes
        break

    # Update the last scroll position
    last_height = new_height
    time.sleep(3) 
    with open("S:/touhami/selenium_results.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    # Print the member list text to the output file
    f.write(member_container.text)
```

I expected to be able to scroll the container I wanted until the end of it and at the same time writing the sidebar content while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why the scroll was not working is that i targeted the wrong class name when i changed it to a nested DIV instead of the parent of the whole container it worked it's scrolling.

**Problem** : now is that it doesnt scroll until the end of the container, it scorlls like 3 times only
also on S:\touhami\selenium_results.txt it writes only the last text available on the screen (i should got like 90 lines with those 3 scrolls instead of like 30 that im geting now)